# ipython qtconsole: drawing multiple functions inside one plot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, ipython

In `ipython-qtconsole`, I can easily create a simple plot:

```
ipython qtconsole --pylab=inline

x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000)
plot(x, sin(x))
```

[image]

Is there a way to specify multiple functions to be drawn inside the same plot ?
I have tried the following, but neither works:

```
plot(x, sin(x), cos(x))
plot(x, [sin(x), cos(x)])
plot(x, {sin(x), cos(x)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write multiple `plot` commands on the same line, separated with a comma:

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000)
plot(x, sin(x)), plot(x, cos(x))
```

[image]

Comment: If you specify the format as well you dont even have to call plot twice:
`plot(x, sin(x), 'r-', x, cos(x), 'b-')`

Answer (score 1):

You can define a figure and axes, draw all the plots and then display the figure. Creating them will also display the empty figure once, i dont know if that can be supressed.

So:

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, sin(x))    
ax.plot(x, cos(x))

display(fig)
```

That would show all functions in the same axes.